# Why does my Text::CSV code split values on spaces when I print them?

Tags: perl, csv

I have the following code that uses `Text::CSV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ({ binary => 0, eol => $/ });
open my $io, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv -> getline ($io)) 
{
    my @fields = @$row;

    while(my $field = <@fields>) 
    {
        print $field."\n";
    }

}
```

(adapted from the [`Text::CSV` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV))

When I try to loop through my `@fields` array after assigning it the values from `@$row`, it breaks up the values on spaces. For instance

```
"FOO","BAR","IM FOO BAR'D"
```

comes out as

```
FOO
BAR
IM
FOO
BAR'D
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
for my $field (@fields)
```

instead of

```
while(my $field = <@fields>)
```

That `while` statement does not do what you think it does.  It's equivalent to

```
while (my $field = glob "@fields")
```

which isn't remotely what you meant.  ([glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) breaks its argument on spaces and tries to expand wildcards, matching files on disk.  Your argument doesn't have any wildcards, so it winds up meaning about the same as `split ' ', "@fields"`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your second loop:

```
while(my $field = <@fields>) 
{
    print $field."\n";
}
```

You can see what's actually going on using [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while (my $field = <@fields>) { print $field."\n" }'
use File::Glob ();
while (defined(my $field = glob(join($", @fields)))) {
    do {
        print $field . "\n"
    };
}
-e syntax OK
```

Let's break that down a bit:

```
join($", @fields)
```

joins the elements of `@fields` into a single string, separated by `$"` (default is a single space). So if `@fields` contains `FOO`, `BAR`, and `IM FOO BAR'D`, the result of the `join` will be

```
FOO BAR IM FOO BAR'D
```

Now, what does `glob` do? From [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

> In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename expansions on the value of `EXPR` such as the standard Unix shell `/bin/csh` would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such filename expansions, returning `undef` when the list is exhausted. This is the internal function implementing the `<*.c>` operator [...]
>
> **Note that glob splits its arguments on whitespace and treats each segment as separate pattern.**

So

```
glob("FOO BAR IM FOO BAR'D")
```

in scalar context will return `FOO`, followed by `BAR`, followed by `IM`, and so on.

As [cjm suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181502/176646), change your loop to something like this to fix:

```
foreach my $field (@fields) 
{
    print "$field\n";
}
```

Or better yet, instead of copying the contents of `@$row` into `@fields` and looping through `@fields`, simply loop through `@$row` directly:

```
foreach my $field (@$row) {
    print "$field\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ThisSuitisBalckNot and cjm,

for my $field (@fields) 

ended up fixing the code.. I'm still not clear on what "globs" are used for but I know enough to avoid the same mistake again :)

Comment: @stumped221 Say you have a bunch of files with different extensions in a directory `foo/`. Using `glob` you can get the names of all of the `.txt` files like this: `perl -wE say for <foo/*.txt>`. You can also use it to add a prefix or suffix (or both!) to a set of words, e.g. `<foo{bar,baz}>` returns `foobar` and `foobaz`. You can even generate the Cartesian product, e.g. `<{foo,bar}-{apple,orange}>` returns `foo-apple`, `foo-orange`, `bar-apple`, and `bar-orange`. There are many other nifty things you can do, but that should give you an idea.